# I would like to know if there is a better way to write this query (multiple joins of the same table)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

here is the problem:

I have vehicles table in db (fields of this table are not so important), what's important is that each vehicle has a model_id, which refers to the vehicle_models table.

Vehicle models table has id, class, model, series, cm3hp, created_at and updated_at fields.
I need to define the stock age in terms of how many vehicles of the certain model class are on the stock by the given criteria. The criteria being: 0-30 days, 31-60 days, 61-90 days... 360 + days...
I don't know if it is clear enough but let me try to explain even better: For each day range I need to find the count of vehicles with the given model class. There are other criteria but that's not important for what I am trying to find out. To help you better understand the problem I'll include the screenshot of how the structure should look like:

[image]

I am using MySQL 8.

The query I wrote is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT vm.class,
    IFNULL(t1.count, 0) as t1c,
    IFNULL(t2.count, 0) as t2c,
    IFNULL(t3.count, 0) as t3c,
    IFNULL(t4.count, 0) as t4c,
    IFNULL(t5.count, 0) as t5c,
    IFNULL(t6.count, 0) as t6c,
    IFNULL(t7.count, 0) as t7c
FROM vehicle_models vm
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            vm.class as class,
            count(*) as count
        FROM a3s186jg7ffmm0q8.vehicles v
            JOIN vehicle_models vm 
            ON vm.id = v.model_id
        WHERE 
            DATEDIFF(IFNULL(v.retail_date, now()), v.wholesale_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
        GROUP BY vm.class
    ) t1 ON t1.class = vm.class
    *** MORE SAME LEFT JOINS ***
ORDER BY vm.class;
```

Now, this provides desired results, but what I would like to know if there is a better way to write this query in terms of performance and also code structure.

Comment: Join once, remove the `where` criteria and use `conditional aggregation` for the count.

Comment: ty for your answer, I'll give it a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guesss you are presenting a report of inventory aging (of how long that car sits on the dealer's lot before somebody buys it).   You can put the age ranges in your top-level select rather than putting each one in a separate subquery.  That will make your query faster (subqueries have a cost) and shorter / easier to read.

Try something like this nested query.  The inner query gives back one row per vehicle with its aging number. The outer query aggregates them.

```sql
SELECT class,
       COUNT(*) total,
       SUM(age BETWEEN 0 AND 30) t1c,
       SUM(age BETWEEN 31 AND 60) t2c,
       SUM(age BETWEEN 61 AND 90) t3c,
       ... etc ...
  FROM (
      SELECT vm.class, 
             DATEDIFF(IFNULL(v.retail_date, now()), v.wholesale_date) age
        FROM a3s186jg7ffmm0q8.vehicles v
        JOIN vehicle_models vm  ON vm.id = v.model_id
       ) subq
 GROUP BY class
 ORDER BY class;
```

This SUM() trick works in MySQL because expressions like `age BETWEEN 0 AND 30` have the value 1 when true and 0 when false.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, mate... ty...